# Find a string and replace it with another string with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with below format:

Available Text1

```
Id                = 0005      
 Cause          = ERROR      
 Code     = 307      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:16:48      
 Severity      = WARNING      
 Severity Code = 5     
 result       = 2015-06-12 10:19:47
 Id                = 0006      
 Cause          = FAILURE      
 Code     = 517      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:19:47      
 Severity      = MINOR      
 Severity Code = 4 result = noresult 
 ip[10.1.1.1
```

I want to find result = in each text file and fulfill the value with the IP.

Requested Data

```
 Id                = 0005      
 Cause          = ERROR      
 Code     = 307      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:16:48      
 Severity      = WARNING      
 Severity Code = 5     
 result = 10.1.1.1
 Id                = 0006      
 Cause          = FAILURE      
 Code     = 517      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:19:47      
 Severity      = MINOR      
 Severity Code = 4 
 result = 10.1.1.1
 ip[10.1.1.1
```

I used the below code, but it only finds no result value and replace it with IP however there is a `datetime` value (`2015-06-12 10:19:47`) with comes in another line as the value of result. How can I use a regex to first find any value after `result=` and then replace it with `IP`?

```
for filepath in file_list:
    txt = open(filepath, "r").read()
    txt = txt.replace("noresult", txt.split("ip[")[-1])
    open(filepath, "w").write(txt)
```

Comment: Use `re.sub()` with an appropriate regular expression.

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas and numpy?

Comment: @rv.kvetch: Yes, I totally understood and updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try with `str.rfind` or `str.rsplit` along with `re.sub`:

```py
import re

s = """\
Id                = 0005
 Cause          = ERROR
 Code     = 307
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:16:48
 Severity      = WARNING
 Severity Code = 5
 result       = 2015-06-12 10:19:47
 Id                = 0006
 Cause          = FAILURE
 Code     = 517
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:19:47
 Severity      = MINOR
 Severity Code = 4 result = noresult
 ip[10.1.1.1
"""

# len('ip[') == 3
ip_addr = s[s.rfind('ip[') + 3:].rstrip('\n')
s = re.sub(r'(result\s*=).*', rf'\1 {ip_addr}', s)
print(s)
```

Out:

```
Id                = 0005
 Cause          = ERROR
 Code     = 307
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:16:48
 Severity      = WARNING
 Severity Code = 5
 result       = 10.1.1.1
 Id                = 0006
 Cause          = FAILURE
 Code     = 517
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:19:47
 Severity      = MINOR
 Severity Code = 4 result = 10.1.1.1
 ip[10.1.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks , The only problem is as you see above in the Available Text1, we have not only no result as a value of result but also 2015-06-12 10:19:47 which is a datetime, I want to replace both value with IP.

Comment: ohh I see it now.. my bad, I think i missed it when I was skimming it over.

Comment: @SaraDaniel I updated my code, see above

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace **result=ANYTHING** to **result=IP**.
In this case you may use re.sub() with a regular expression that matches every thing after "result=".

```
import re
re.sub(r"result =[^\n]+","result = ip[10.1.1.1",txt)
```

The `[^\n]+` will match every char in a single line.

To extract the IP from the text and do the replacement:

```
ip=re.findall(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",txt)[0]

txt=re.sub(r"result =[^\n]+","result = "+ip)
```

Comment: Thanks, please be informed that I have multiple text files and the value of IP is not static in each file, for example in the first file it is 10.1.1.1 but in the second file it is 10.1.1.2, I want to know if it is possible to search for IP as regex and replace it to value of result = Anything.

Comment: Based on above comment can we use it like : re.sub(r"result =[^\n]+",txt.split("ip[")[-1],txt)

Comment: If the position of IP is fixed in all files, then txt.split("ip[")[-1] will work for you, otherwise you can use the following to extract the IP: ip=re.findall(r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b",txt)[0]. Then use the code in the answer to replace result = Anything to result = ip